# For and While loop in php mysql

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, phpmyadmin, while-loop

I have the following code. Is there any way to combine and simplify it?

The output in the json.html file should be like this: `["abc","def","ghi"]`.

```
    <?php
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "admin") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("test1") or die(mysql_error());

    // Get all the data from the "example" table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test_auto_complete") or die(mysql_error());  

    $menu = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $menu[] = array("id" => $row['username'],);
    } 

    foreach($menu as $key=>$value)
    {
      $menu[$key] = $value['id'];
    }


    $my_json_content = json_encode($menu);

    $file = 'json.html';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    file_put_contents($file, $my_json_content);

    ?>
```

I know the code looks bad, but even so, can someone help me?

Thanks
Haan

Comment: don't use mysql_* change them to PDO or mysqli cause mysql_* are depracated. It seems you don't use $current variable so why you get the content of file? What do you want to use foreach for I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put content in file than just use `file_put_contents`

```
$my_json_content = json_encode($menu);
$file = 'json.html';
file_put_contents($file, $my_json_content);
```

And use this `while` loop without `foreach`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$menu[] = $row['username'];
}
```

Comment: he uses it but he uses also file_get_contents for no reason.

Comment: @RobertPodwika May be OP needs some rest ..:)

Answer (score 0):

I won't even give you solution with mysql_* because they are depracated look at the solution in PDO

```
<?php 
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test1;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'admin';

try{
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $menu = array();
    foreach ($conn->query("SELECT * FROM test_auto_complete") as $row)
             $menu[] = $row['username'];

    file_put_contents('json.html', json_encode($menu));

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**Tips:**

1. Mysql_* functions are depracated and they don't support a lot of features of MySQL
2. Foreach in your case was senseless.
3. File_get_contents() in your code does not have any sense for me, what do you need the content of file for?
4. Variables are used for data which is going to be changed. For example in your case you use variable for **json.html** which seems to be constant, if so, then use constant string.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\jquery-auto-complete\mycheck.php on line 9
Getting this error message when i used your code :(